# How to compare two files that have the same unsorted (and additional unimportant) content?

Tags: python, compare

I have two files and two scenarios:

1. Both files have the same content, but not the same content order. For example:

   - File 1: `tom albert jim`
   - File 2: `albert jim tom`
2. Both files have the same important content (e.g. `jim`, `albert`, and `tom`) and additional unimportant content (e.g. `jack` or `jason`) that should be left out. For example:

   - File 1: `tom albert jim jason`
   - File 2: `albert jim tom`

A simple `true` or `false` would do. Of course, in both examples here, the output should be `true`. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the "important content" always the same ? i.e. "jim, albert & tom ?

Comment: Sry forgot to mention that: No this is just an example. The content varies.

Comment: How about doubles in the input? E. g. `tom tom albert tom jim` and `albert jim jim tom`?

Comment: as long as the important content exists in both files it's fine. 1 file is the initiator e.g. the file 2 (albert jim tom) if file file 1 has 2x jim it shouldn't matter. but if the initiator file has two (jim jim) then of course the other file should have the same amount

Comment: to the first comment: I hope I got u right. The content varies in every new iteration. specifically iteration1: 2files f1 and f2. one is the master file with the important content. the second is checked against it. true/false

Comment: That would mean you have to count the amounts for each possible input token and see whether the _initiator_ file has a smaller amount than the _other_ file.  Except when the _initator_ file has an amount of zero, then the _other_ file also must have an amount of zero.  Is this description correct?  (And is this really what you want?  Sounds like a very strange usecase.)

Comment: @Duboe: I add a simple length of list compare to improve the process and also prevent exception in for loop in case of list index out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes that your input is logically a *bag* of values, i. e. that values are counted, but their position doesn't matter.  It also assumes that larger amounts in the *other* file than in the *initiator* file are okay, but not vice versa.  Finally, it assumes that only values in the *initiator* file are allowed to appear in the *other* file.

① Read both files, ② split the contents of each (maybe by spaces?) into a *bag* (we use `collections.Counter` for this), ③ check if there are unfulfilled demands of the *initiator* file, ④ check if there are unexpected values in the *other* file.

① Read both files:

```
with open('initiator') as f:
  contentsI = f.read()
with open('other') as f:
  contentsO = f.read()
```

② Split the contents into sets, removing all unwanted stuff in the process:

```
from collections import Counter
tokensI = Counter(value for value in contentsI.split()
                        if value not in [ 'unwanted1', 'unwanted2' ])
tokensO = Counter(value for value in contentsO.split()
                        if value not in [ 'unwanted1', 'unwanted2' ])
```

③ & ④ Compare the bags:

```
return not (tokensI - tokensO) and not (set(tokensO) - set(tokensI))
```

Comment: it's not completely related to the question but do u know how I set a range for the unwanted content? e.g. if value not in ['< and everyting in those brackets>']

Comment: That `if` statement in the comprehension there is arbitrary, so you can also write things like `if (value not in [ 'unwanted1', 'unwanted1' ]) and ((value < 5) or (value > 10))` or how ever you would like to denote your condition.

Comment: If with 'range' you meant giving the tokens as a string, you can use this: `if value not in "one two three".split()`.  I'm not sure how to understand your question ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, simply order by alphabet before compare one by one item. hope this help

```
#Let's call f1 and f2 are string that you read from f1 and f2
f1 = 'tom albert jim jason'
f2 = 'jack albert jim tom'

unimportant_list = ['jim', 'albert', 'tom'] #this should be defined somewhere

#make list data of f1, f2. word split by a space and remove item in unimportant_list
list1 = [x for x in f1.split(' ') if x not in unimportant_list]
list2 = [x for x in f2.split(' ') if x not in unimportant_list]

#sort both list for easy compare
list1.sort()
list2.sort()

#compare length of 2 list first for better performance and also prevent exception in the for loop
if not len(list1) == len(list2):
    return false

#compare 2 list one by one
result = true
for i in range (len(list1)):
    if not list1[i] == list2[i]: #if some item not equal mean 2 list is not same
        result = false
return result
```